# How to synchronize Google geocoding and Google places suggest results?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I have address suggestion (input with dropdown) and map address picking features on my website.

Address suggestion uses Google Places API to provide address list by given string.

Map address picking feature uses Google reverse geocoding API to provide address by coordinates.

The problem:
If user picks the same house from map Google reverse geocoding provides:

`{
               "long_name" : "Appenzell Steinegg",
               "short_name" : "Appenzell Steinegg",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },`

If user choose suggested address Google places API provides:

`{
            "long_name" : "Rüte",
            "short_name" : "Rüte",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },`

So, there is no way to get the same result. Full Address is the same, but 2 APIs provide different address object.

Addresses used for tests (the same address):

- Egglistrasse 4, 9050 Rüte, Switzerland (Commune `Rute`)
- Egglistrasse 4, 9050 Appenzell Steinegg, Switzerland (Cantone `Appenzell Innerrhoden`, Village `Steinegg`)

Comment: You're comparing the results of 2 different APIs (Geocoding and Place Autocomplete) for ambiguous input "Egglistrasse 4, 9050" (I think). This would be better reported in the Maps APIs issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789006

Comment: Your input contains Two different long_name and short_name. And it seems to limit the search based on these limits: "Appenzell Steinegg" and "Rüte".